# iOS bring subview to back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want ot bring a view to appear on the top of another view.

Here is my view hierarchy:

[image]

Basically I want to bring the button(Start Again) in front of the UIImageView which belongs to PageViewController. So I want to be able to scroll with the button on the top of the images.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Comment: Don't just throw all your code at the wall like spaghetti and expect us to analyze it for you. What is the _actual problem_? Bringing a view to the front is trivially easy; why and where is it hard for _you_?

Comment: I cut the size of the posted code.

Comment: If you want the button (which I assume is a subview of the parent view) to appear above the `PageViewController`, then you either need to send the view of the `PageViewController` to the back or bring the subview to the front. Did you try this? Did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@iamataptool** suggested I brought the `PageViewController` to back with:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack: _pageViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using following code?

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButtonView];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using storyboard and programmatic UIView positioning in parallel. Therefore you have different possible solutions:

**Fix the symptoms by manually pushing it up <-- not recommended** Push your buttonView in front of all your other views (also the embedded ones) by

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButtonView];
```

Nevertheless, as mentioned,  this only fixes the symptom, but if you want to add more 'overlaying' elements, you would have to do that for all of them. Better would be:

**Or the programmatic approach:** 
Add your UIButton programmatically instead of the storyboard after you added the view of the `UIPageViewController` to your view hierarchy. So after you did this

```
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
```

Simply instantiate a UIButton with your configuration and add it via

```
[self.view addSubview:yourProgrammaticallyCreatedButton];
```

**Or add a container view <-- My recommendation** 
Add another view (we can call it container view) under your button - but don't add the button to that containerview. Give it constraints to have the same frame as your `UIViewController`'s view. Hold a `IBOutlet` to that `UIView` and use this view to add the UIPageViewControllers view.

```
 _pageViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
 [self.containerView addSubView: _pageViewController.view]
```